# How do I paginate or batch a call to mssql_execute()?

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

When I make a call to an MSSQL database using ad-hoc SQL (for example, `"SELECT foo FROM tablename"`), I can give a batch size for that call. This is very useful when I expect a lot of data returned.

In my case, I have a table with over 200 million rows, and I'm getting them all. Yes, I have reasons for being a big slurpy data hog like this.

My DB guys said, "Hey, stop using ad-hoc SQL, here, use this nifty SP. It does the same thing."

So I'm using it with the `mssql_execute()` function call, but there's no way to specify a batch size when doing this as there is with `mssql_query()`

I not only have to do a `ini_set('memory_limit', '64G')`; to make this work, I also have to sweat things as the SP call takes upwards of a half hour to run. Once it runs, I can do a loop on `mssql_fetch_row()`, no problem, but that initial call is a nail-biter!

And once I'm done, I have a process taking up 57G of memory (on a 96G box) that then takes a full hour at 80% CPU just to unwind and garbage collect. Yeah, I could kill the process, but that's a hack.

There has to be a better way!

With ad-hoc SQL, I call `mssql_query()` with a batch size of 10,000 rows and process them and then go back for more. I can then do something like echo "Yes, indeed, I'm on row `$i` right now..." and salve my paranoia that everything is running right.

So... what's the appropriate way to do this if I'm forced to use the SP that my DB guys want me to use?

Comment: Did you ask your DB guys what they suggest you do ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming the table has a primary key, I suggest you ask the DB guys to add 2 parameters to the stored procedure, one for the number of rows to be returned and another for the starting key value.  Pass NULL for the initial batch and the last key value returned for each subsequent batch.  This will provide efficient forward-only pagination.  For example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.usp_select_tablename
      @NumRows int
    , @StartKey int = NULL
AS 
IF @StartKey IS NULL
BEGIN
    SELECT TOP(@NumRows) foo
    FROM tableName
    ORDER BY StartKey;
END
ELSE
BEGIN
    SELECT TOP(@NumRows) foo
    FROM tableName
    WHERE Key > @StartKey
    ORDER BY StartKey;
END;
```